# All data in IDA Pro turns into zeros when using QEMU

Tags: ida, firmware, arm, qemu

I'm trying to [emulate](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=111) a snippet of ARM assembly I have in IDA pro using QEMU. However I do not understand the output of the program.

When I start debugging the firmware, windows pop up for QEMU.
However all the data in IDA turns into zeros, as can be seen in the picture below.

Why is this happening?

Is this normal behavior of the program?

[image: the data is replaced by zeros]

Other information:

- Windows 8.1
- IDA 6.8
- QEMU 2.7.0 (32 bit) from http://qemu.weilnetz.de/

the binary I am trying to emulate is for a device with:

- armv7-m architecture

the gdb debug configuration command line is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\qemu/qemu-system-arm" -S -gdb tcp::%p,ipv4 -kernel "%e" -M versatilepb -cpu cortex-a8
```

The initial SP is 0x20000000
and the memory map looks like this

[image]

Comment: In absence of other information, an obvious hypothesis would be that you misconfigured something. Check the guide you linked again.

Comment: @VitalyOsipov I added more information to the question.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have been running into this  with remote GDB debugging.

Comment: @ApertureSecurity No, as far as I remember I didn't.